# Call Void from Extern "C" function in .mm file

Tags: cocoa, unity-game-engine, objective-c++

Is it possible to call a function from Extern "C" in the same script?

In Xcode, in a .mm script I'm using to bridge a framework to work with Unity (basically making a plugin), I have a function:

```
 @implementation MyBridge
   -(void)DoThis{
     //do something;
   }
 @end
```

And then below that, **in the same script,** I have an extern "C" function which I use to communicate with unity.

there's a function in my extern "C" section, which I want to use to call the "DoThis" function.

```
 extern "C"{
   void _DoSomething(){
     //do the DoThis function under @implementation
   }
 }
```

How would I go about calling the *DoThis* function from my *_DoSomething* function? Is it possible?

Comment: `[[[MyBridge alloc] init] DoThis]`?

Comment: Wow, it took you 5 seconds to answer what I searched for hours to find. Thank you. The error went away. I'll come back if it didn't work, but I'm off to go test it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: I wrote [[MyBridge alloc] DoThis] and it worked. Why did you add in init? Is it substantial?

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you read a guide on Objective-C programming.

Comment: It'd be great to see @一二三's comment written up as an answer. For an Objective-C outsider like myself it is very counter intuitive that one can write Objective-C syntax within a C or C++ function.